# clear the text field or destroy the object

Tags: apache-flex

I have a text field, which holds the session value. Now while when i do logout operation.. clearing the text field does not work...

```
sessionHold.text = "";
```

The above code does not work, its not clearing the session value in the field.

```
appSes = event.result as Array 
var vinoth:String = String(appSes[0]);
Alert.show(vinoth);
sessionHold.text = appSes[1];
```

Now i am slightly confused....

Comment: May need some more code for context.  I don't know much about flex, but depending on when you are trying to perform the text clear action, it may be too late in the page life cycle for the screen to be painted with the change.

Comment: yeah... does your code run in that order? Because you have sessionHold.text = appSes[1]; at the end...?

Comment: The below code runs on ResultEvent and the above code runs after that when the event has finished.

Comment: You should post more code so we can help you debug in context.  If you explicitly set sessionHold.text = "" like that, the text field will be cleared on the next screen update, unless you're not hitting that line for some reason, the symbol name is no longer valid, or you're rewriting the textField's text property again, after clearing it, and not realizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need to hold the session id inside a text field and not inside a String varialble ?!